# how do i get ALL the value inside the parenthesis?

Tags: php

i need to get all the string/content inside each parenthesis inside of a string.
example: `$string = "hello (cool) how are you (i am okay) where are you from (i am from earth)";` i am using preg_match_all like this `preg_match_all('#\((.*?)\)#', $nonumber, $match);` and then once i get the content of whatever is inside the parenthesis i want to put it in array

so i want each content inside parenthesis and put it into array like this.

the first array will have the value of cool

the second one will have value of i am okay

i tried to echo $match[0] but i get error  Array to string conversion.

to put it simply i want the value to be inside an array. like this 
$match[0] will have value of cool
$match[1] will have value of i am okay 
and so on

like an array that you can call the value

i am desperate and dont know how to fix this. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track to use `preg_match_all`, but you should use the pattern `\((.*?)\)`:

```
$regexp = "/\((.*?)\)/"; 
$string = "hello (cool) how are you (i am okay) where are you from (i am from earth)";
preg_match_all($regexp, $string, $matches); 
foreach ($matches[1] as $value) {
    echo $value . "\n";
}

cool
i am okay
i am from earth
```

### Demo

Comment: how do i get the value from each one of them separately. like an array example $match[0] will have value of cool. and $match[1] have value of i am okay

Comment: Check my updated answer; just iterate the first (not zeroth) entry of `$matches`; it will contain all the first capture group results.

Comment: i think i could use this. hold on

Comment: `to put it simply i want the value to be inside an array` ... the `$matches[1]` array is precisely what you want, unless I read incorrectly, or you explained wrongly.

Comment: you got it right i was thinking of inserting that value into mysql. i was imagining it to look like an array,because that is the way i used to do it. but i could just directly insert the value into mysql this way too. thank you